# ssh'ing into my home machine without a static IP address

Tags: networking, ssh, dynamic-ip

I currently have a static ip address with Comcast.    I'd like to switch to Sonic, but they don't offer static IP's in my area.   I'm wondering if I would still be able to get into my machine from outside my LAN with a dynamic IP address.      I've just always had a static address and am a noob, so wouldn't know how to proceed without it.    I know there are a bunch of posts relating to this, but I'm pretty clueless so was hoping for a low-tech solution.    Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Using a dynamic DNS provider **is** the low-tech solution.

Comment: The idea is to somehow broadcast your dynamic ip to a specific global point every time the network renews/change so that you can learn from it and ssh using that ip, so you need to setup a script (may be with cron to routinely check) on your machine behind dynamic ip to learn the ip and then send it to like your mailbox or something.

Comment: Some routers offer an option to use dynamic DNS service (e.g. Fritzbox does).

Comment: Even though my ISP doesn't offer Static IP's, it hasn't changed in over a year....Maybe no solution is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to use a Dynamic DNS service (DDNS).  There are free and paid solutions, and it's really not particularly hard to set up.  Once you set it up, you will always have the same URL no matter what IP address you have.  I use it to access my computer via SSH, and also my router's USB drive via FTP.

I've been using noip.com for years.  They have a free plan if you want to try it out. The enhanced plan ($20/year) gives you more choices for domain names, and doesn't require monthly access.

You usually pick a domain like "ddns.net" (one of the free ones), and prepend any name in front that's available, usually your name, or something unique.  Then, you need to tell noip your ip address, which can be either automated or manual (to test it out).  There is an updater that can run automatically and update it when changed, or many routers can do it for you.